# Convert docx to pdf with Word Automation Services

Tags: sharepoint, service, ms-word, automation, office-automation

With the help of this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff742315.aspx I tried doing an conversion from docx to pdf on sharepoint ...
1) I created a cs file on the sharepoint server ...
2) I compiled with a a bat file to a console exe
3) The exe runs but gives an exception  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The files exist and are editable at \mysrv\sites\casedocs\Documents\ElfDev\10080003 and at https:\mysrv\sites\casedocs\Documents\ElfDev\10080003, the latter with no cert error.

**1) The Cs file ...**

```
using System ; 
using System.Collections.Generic ; 
using System.Linq ; 
using System.Text ; 
using Microsoft.SharePoint ; 
using Microsoft.Office.Word.Server.Conversions ; 
class Program
{
  static void Main( string[] args )
  {
 string siteUrl = "https://mysrv" ; 
 string wordAutomationServicesName = "Word Automation Services" ; 
 string source = siteUrl + "/sites/casedocs/Documents/ElfDev/10080003/JK1.docx" ; 
 string target = siteUrl + "/sites/casedocs/Documents/ElfDev/10080003/jk1.pdf" ; 
 using( SPSite spSite = new SPSite(siteUrl) ) 
 {
   ConversionJob job = new ConversionJob(wordAutomationServicesName ) ; 
   job.UserToken = spSite.UserToken ; 
   job.Settings.UpdateFields = true ; 
   job.Settings.OutputFormat = SaveFormat.PDF ; 
      // System.Null reference exception on next line ...
   job.AddFile( source ,  target   )  ; 
 }
  }
}
```

**2) The compiler bat file ...**

```
csc /out:d2p.exe /target:exe d2pMain.cs /r:"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll" /r:"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI\Microsoft.Office.Word.Server.dll"
```

**3. The full exception ...**

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Office.Word.Server.FolderIterator.CheckInputFile(SPListItem item )
   at Microsoft.Office.Word.Server.FolderIterator.CheckSingleItem(SPFile inputFile, SPFile outputFile)
   at Microsoft.Office.Word.Server.Conversions.ConversionJob.AddFileCore(String inputFileName, String outputFileName)
   at Microsoft.Office.Word.Server.Conversions.ConversionJob.AddFile(String inputFile, String outputFile)   at Program.Main(String[] args)
```

It looks like it cannot see the input file, but 
a) \mysrv\sites\casedocs\Documents\ElfDev\10080003\jk1.docx will open the file in word 2010
and 
b) https://mysrv/sites/casedocs/Documents/ElfDev/10080003/jk1.docx opens the file in Word 2010

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when running within a console application, and you do not have a HTTP Context when you are using the Server version of the Microsoft.SharePoint.dll.

The code blows up because it is expecting to have the HTTP content in the Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext variable.

In order for this code to work, you must run it within the SharePoint IIS web server.

Convert your code to a class, compile it into a SharePoint feature and solution package (.WSP) and deploy it to the SharePoint Farm.  Then the code will work, because the Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContent will be populated and won't be null.